# Installation of SSDs in R610

Tags: installation, ssd

I am about to order a Dell R610. I have also ordered SATA Intel 730 SSD's for it. Is there anything I need apart from drive trays (G176J) for installation? Ie is there any other back plane this or that which is needed? This seems like a really simple question and maybe the SSD is just screwed into a tray like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/G176J-2-5-SAS-SATA-HDD-Hard-Drive-Tray-Caddy-Screws-for-DELL-R610-R710-R810-F-/131213338124?pt=UK_Computing_Drive_Bay_Caddies&hash=item1e8ceca60c) And that is the end of it, or maybe there are other adaptors or parts needed? I have tried surfing around but maybe it is so obvious that it is not even stated? Can someone who has done this before tell me?

Thanks,
   Jas

Comment: **Summary Answer**: _Only the drive trays and the SSDs are needed._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you bought a jank-tastic model that's been unreasonably stripped down, you only need the tray. The drive slides into the SATA ports on the backplane as its guided by the grooves that the tray fits in.

> I have tried surfing around but maybe it is so obvious that it is not even stated?

I wasn't going to say anything, but since you brought the topic up... =)

Comment: I agree, but only thing @sysjas must make sure is the SSD drive is supported by the controller. I seen a lot of thread that the some drives are not recognized in the controller. As it seem to be bougth by another source than Dell.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I guess there are standard holes on the standard tray and you just need to make sure the back of the SSD is flush with the end of the tray? Then when you insert the tray the distance to the back plane is exactly correct. If that is correct, then that is all I need to know... Thanks!

Comment: @sysjas There's no holes in the back of the tray, it's just an open backed holder that you screw into the hard drive. The screws will line up just right and you won't have to worry about if anything is flush with anything else.

Comment: @Wesley, Ahh. Great. I had thought that might be the case that the distances are all standard and there is no way to "stuff it up". Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: @sysjas Your project trackabus looks interesting. Let me know if you need any consulting. It's what I do; contact details in my profile. =)

Comment: @yagmoth555, thanks for the comment. Yes I searched around a lot before settling on the Intel 730 SSDs. From what I have read they have the best chance of being compatible while being in normal pricing territory (i.e. not the 2 to 3 times more expensive for enterprise level drives). The Intel 730s appear to be very similar to their enterprise cousins the S3500/S3700 series see [anandtech](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7803/intel-ssd-730-480gb-review) they have power-loss protection, the same controller, etc.